# Is there a way to duplicate a cell as an inserted row (one row below the target cell) for each line of text in the target cell?

Tags: excel, parsing, insert, duplicates, formula

I am spinning my wheels on this... Is there a way to duplicate a cell as an inserted row (one row below the target cell) for each line of text in the target cell? Is there a way to duplicate a cell as an inserted row (one row below the target cell) for each line of text in the target cell?

So I have this cell. I have hundreds of them:

```
1010101010
1010110101
10001010101010
101001010101010
101010101010010
10101010101010
101010011010
```

It is in a row with other formatting and columns. Just some minor things like counting char length.

I want to take each line there in the binary cell, duplicate it, and insert it sequentially from the top down one row underneath itself. Excluding the first line. So starting on the second line I need to insert a row for each line.

Is there a way to automate this for the entire sheet with a function? I have been trying to find a way.

I am new to excel programming and functions so any help at all or a point in the right direction even would be very appreciated.

Even a way to do it cell by cell would be better. A VBA code perhaps to add a row below the row with multiple lines of text for each line of text. Have the text in those rows starting with the second line of text in the first below the cell we are breaking up. I can then remove the rest of the lines manually or if the code can sweep them that would work to.

[image: This is the data I have hundreds of these rows]

I need to break them out like this. It takes me extremely long to add the rows manually because of the amount of data in the file that needs to be calculated.

[image: Desired format]

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with a function, since a function only returns a value to a cell. It does not change the structure of a worksheet.

You can do this with code, which might take some time to write, but if it's a one-off, you can also do it without code.

- work out how many rows of data you have, for example by jumping to the end of the column. Say you have 100 rows.
- insert a column before column A and in the new column A manually type the numbers 1 and 3 into cells A2 and A3 (I assume row 1 has a label. If not, start in cell A1)
- double-click the Fill Handle to fill the number sequence all the way down. It should have the numbers 1,3,5,7,9, etc in the column, ending at 199.
- below the last row of data, without leaving a gap, put the numbers 2 and 4 into the next  two rows.
- using the fill handle or your preferred method of filling down, complete the series until you get to 200, i.e. create a series with 100 rows below the 100 rows of data.
- you will now have in column A the series 1,3,5,7 up to 199, followed by 2,4,6,8 etc, up to 200.
- Select all the columns and sort by column A

Now every other row is blank. To duplicate the cell from the row above

- select column B, or whichever column contains the values you want to duplicate
- hit F5 to open the Go To dialog
- click Special
- Tick Blanks and OK
- now all blank cells in the column are selected and cell B3 (if B1 has labels) is active.
- without moving the selection, type a `=` sign
- use the Up Arrow key on the keyboard. The cell now contains the formula `=B2`
- hold down the Ctrl key and hit Enter

Now all previously selected blank cells have a formula that shows the value from the cell above. You can now use Copy / Paste Values to paste the results over the formulas and continue with your work. Remove column A, which is no longer required.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response. I still do not see how this code is parsing the lines in my field into multiple rows

Comment: Well, in that case, I guess your title just doesn't "say it all", despite you repeating it several times. Maybe you need to edit your question and illustrate your desired outcome with a Before and After sample in a screenshot, where we can see Excel cells. Text in a question is so much less informative.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am attaching the before and after screen shots of what I am trying to do. For each one of these cells that I have multiple lines of text in. I want to insert a row BELOW the row each line is in. Starting with the first line in the first row below. The text of the line will be in the row associated with the line.

Comment: please offer any advice if you can. Thankyou